# How to normalize DICOM images coming from different sources?

Tags: python, dicom

I am trying to plot a list of echography Dicom images using pydicom and pyplot. 
The images have different pixels value (for some images values ranges from 0 to 4000: category 1) for others from (0 to 16000: category 2). 
Plotted images from the 2nd category have this look (notice that we can see almost nothing inside the echography). For the category 1 the images are clear.

I already tested the conversion to HU units but the slope and intercept read from all the images are respectively 1 and 0 so nothing changed.

The code

```
import numpy as np 
import pydicom as dicom 
ds = dicom.read_file(path_dcm) 
plt.imshow(np.invert(ds.pixel_array), cmap =plt.cm.bone)
```

I expect images to be looking like echography with black background and where we can see what it is inside the organ may be by making some transformations using the parameters in the metadata.

Here is the current plot for category 2 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwjgv.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no solution for your problem. Rescale Slope and Intercept are only referring to HU in CT images. Unless both images have an identical value in Rescale Type (0028,1054) the grayscales of the images are unrelated.

It may be worth a try to multiply the category 1 images' pixel values by 4 so that you receive a similar range. But without a normalized reference scale there is no guarantee that this is going to work in all cases.